# Numbering duplicate rows in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to number rows in which column a and column b is a match and when they occur again regardless of the date.

The dataset looks like this and I want the row_number column:

| rider | driver | date | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jim | joe | 2020-10-20 | 1 |
| jim | joe | 2020-10-28 | 2 |
| jim | jack | 2020-10-29 | 1 |
| jim | joe | 2020-10-31 | 3 |
| john | jane | 2020-10-29 | 1 |
| john | jane | 2020-10-31 | 2 |

I thought about using the function <row_number over partition by> but I don't think it worked..
Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: why do you think `row_number()` does not work?

Comment: not sure how to use it honestly :/ I think row_number() is the answer but i'm not sure which column it is that i should state in the order by parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row_number() is actually for what you are looking for.

```
WITH data as (

SELECT "jim" as rider, "joe" as driver, "2020-10-20" as date UNION ALL
SELECT "jim", "joe", "2020-10-28" UNION ALL
SELECT "jim", "jack" , "2020-10-29" UNION ALL
SELECT "jim", "joe","2020-10-31" UNION ALL
SELECT "john", "jane", "2020-10-29"  UNION ALL
SELECT "john", "jane", "2020-10-31" )

SELECT 
  rider, driver, date, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by rider, driver) as row_number
FROM data
ORDER by rider, driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below - usually numbering tightly coupled with some particular order which in your case is clearly defined by data - so I do think it is important here to have `order by` within the window definition

```
select *, 
  row_number() over win as row_number
from `project.dataset.table`
window win as (partition by rider, driver order by date)
```